# Combining multiple character vectors of different lengths into single matrix without recycling

Tags: r

I have a list of c.1100 individual character vectors, each of which corresponds to a particular set of genes (the character is the gene symbol in the form: e.g. "ENSG000011", "ENSG000012" etc.

I want to merge these vectors into a single data.frame/matrix, such that each item in the list becomes its own column. However, each of the items in the list is of a different length.

However, I cannot seem to find a single way of doing this.

I've tried a number of ways within R, but the format never seems to look quite right (e.g. it pastes all of the items of the list in one row, on top of oneanother, or I get an error as the elements are each of different lengths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Base R we need to...

First lets create a sample dataset with 4 vectors:

```
a <- rnorm(10)
b <- rnorm(5)
c <- rnorm(7)
d <- rnorm(20)
```

Then we can put them in a list as:

```
f <- list(a,b,c,d)
```

Then we need to find the `length` of the longest vector:

```
max_len <- max(sapply(f, length))
```

Then we need to make all vectors the `max_len` by substituting `NA`s in for the gap (so if you have a `max_len = 20` and a current vector is only `length(current) = 10` then you need the last 10 values to be `NA`

```
f1 <- lapply(f, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max_len - length(x))))
```

Then you can turn this into a matrix as:

```
matrix(unlist(f1), ncol = length(f1), byrow = F)
```

which results in

```
             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
 [1,] -0.53487289 -1.8570456  0.8304454 -0.6440267
 [2,]  0.04283173 -1.2541836  0.9579962 -1.1664334
 [3,] -1.31686110 -0.6789986  0.9424487  0.4073388
 [4,] -0.54987484 -0.4326257 -1.5165032  0.1990406
 [5,]  0.31529161 -0.2712977  0.1347272 -0.2479010
 [6,] -1.08465865         NA  0.7442857 -1.1319033
 [7,]  1.11283161         NA -0.8397640  0.2636702
 [8,]  0.08882676         NA         NA -0.1332037
 [9,]  0.76028752         NA         NA  0.1607880
[10,] -2.68513818         NA         NA -2.3300150
[11,]          NA         NA         NA -0.3356175
[12,]          NA         NA         NA  0.8115210
[13,]          NA         NA         NA  1.1668857
[14,]          NA         NA         NA  0.5538027
[15,]          NA         NA         NA -0.8910439
[16,]          NA         NA         NA -1.4056796
[17,]          NA         NA         NA -1.6713585
[18,]          NA         NA         NA  0.2557690
[19,]          NA         NA         NA -0.5970861
[20,]          NA         NA         NA  0.1851019
```

Comment: That's great, this worked a treat. thankyou!

Comment: You mind checkmarking my answer?

Comment: All done for you!